# Rails and Testing, why testing controllers is not enough?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, model-view-controller

I was wondering, as testing a controller in rails run the associated views (even if not shown) and integrate many models concerns (by saving, updating,...), testing controller should be almost enough for all applications near enough of CRUD classical architecture. Am I wrong?
Furthermore, views can be tested in the browser, as eyes can be quicker to check than describing everything in a test (and they can achieve CSS control too.)

Thank you for your point of view!

PH

Comment: Eyes might be quicker, but they can't be controlled by a CI server.

Comment: OK, but then we speak about really big project, for me i'm just starting a relatively important project and it's the first time i've to achieve tests, for security concerns. I'm already convinced :-) But at the same time, really simple app doesn't need tests, and checking controllers make dev aware of exception in views. It's like exhaustive combination controlling the 2 sides.

Comment: Exceptions aren't the only types of errors. If you're only going to do one type of testing, do integration testing.

Comment: If anything good tests are important for a small team, because you probably don't have the luxury of a QA team to review everything after an urgent change

Comment: For example, i've 5 models with really specific access rules, I check all CRUD operations for each, with DB seeds for many scenarios (user,roles, ...). If test works, it means that all operation work, that model validation is accomplished correcly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing only your controllers will tell you that, broadly, your app is working, at least in terms of not 500'ing or whatever.  But can you be sure that it is doing the exactly correct thing?  If all you need to test is standard resourceful behaviour like "given `params[:id]`, is the record with id `<params[:id]>` loaded?" then just testing the controller might be enough.

But, you will inevitably add more complicated behaviour into your models.  In this situation, your controller may set some variables or something, without raising an error, by calling a model method.  At this stage, it's much cleaner to test the model method directly, to make sure that given a particular set of conditions, it does the right thing.

Comment: For the moment, testing is for security concern, ie check if rules are correctly respected with a DB seeded in purpose. But just testing controller and security give me the impression of testing already a big part of the app.

Comment: It's true that testing the controller can let you test a good part of your stack in one go.  A lot of the time though the controller is really just passing params on to a model method, and in this case it makes your life easier in the long run to make sure the model is doing exactly what it is supposed to before testing the controller:  controller testing is much much slower than model testing:  you can call the model hundreds of times with different data in a very short time, whereas each controller test requires a bit of waiting around.

Comment: Also, some test purists would say that a controller test should test **only** the controller, and all model method calls should be stubbed out.  This is a fairly "hardcore" option.  If you're interested in "full stack testing" then have a look at automated browser testing.  Selenium IDE used to be the boss for this but i think it's a bit uncool nowadays.  Try http://dalekjs.com/

Comment: Great thanks! It was what I was looking for. I think we don't need to go purist, tests can be a neat way to explore scenarios in an automated way.  http://casperjs.org seems great too.